# Threadsafe version of vsprintf to count length of fmt/args

Tags: c, windows

On a UNIX environment I would use vsnprintf() with a short buffer to get the length of the resulting string. With this information, I can malloc() enough memory to do the actual formatting. like in:

```
va_list  args;
char    *ptr = NULL;
int   len = 0;
char buf[2];

va_start(args, fmt);
len = vsnprintf(buf, 1, fmt, args);

if(len > 0) {
  ptr = malloc(len + 1, "tempdata", 0L);
  vsprintf(ptr, fmt, args);
}
va_end(args);
```

my problem is, I use a very old Windows environment (Microsoft Visual C++6.0/1998), where there is only the function _vsnprintf() which needs a big enough memory to do the counting. Is it threadsafe to use the same static buffer for counting the length?

Comment: nope, edited the question

Comment: Using the same `static` buffer is not thread-safe. Visual 6 supports TLS, though (`TlsAlloc` is in its SDK and its standard library functions like `strtok` use it).

Comment: @2501 i wanted to avoid inventing the wheel. My homeworld is Unix, and this piece of code is "legacy" I have to maintain in conjunction with the new code. The former solution was even wose with tmpnam(), fprintf() and stat().

Comment: maybe I try to look into semaphores

Comment: Mutexes or critical sections would be more appropriate than semaphores. As for TLS, it works as follows: (1) At start of program, call `TlsAlloc` and store result in a global/static. (2) whenever you need your buffer, use `TlsGetValue` to get your pointer (initially NULL), call `malloc/realloc` and `TlsSetValue` as necessary (buffer still NULL or too small)`, and use your buffer. (3) Ideally you'd need to call a cleanup function at the end of your thread, but I don't think there's any built-in mechanism for that, apart from DLLs.